# How to get the windows standard dialog for accepting /declining a digital certificate in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dialog, certificate, x509

When writing a C/S-Application with C# i'm checking the certificate of the server i connect to. Therefore I get a callback where i can consider about `X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors` to check the certificate. I want to let the user decide about it, so thought about using the windows standard certificate dialog, which looks like this:

[image: Windows standard certificate decision dialog]

**How can I achieve this by the given data?**

I've found a partial answer for showing the certificate. Therefore i can use this code:

```
X509Certificate certificate = ...
X509Certificate2 certenh = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(certenh);
```

But the other message is still missing. I could reproduce it, but not for every language, and I've no idea where to find that symbol. As condition for showing this message i could use `certenh.Verify();`.

For the icon of the background message I can use **urlmon.dll** at index 13, 14 and 15. There you find icons like:

[image: Certificate information]
[image: Certificate question]
[image: Certificate warning]

So I'm able to build a similar message like the one in the background. The only problem that is left, is that it would be better to use standard language specific phrases to build the message. But I've found no library that contains the language specific strings.

For the moment I build the message on my own by using the value of `sslPolicyErrors`.

Comment: Good question. Have you tried using [`SelectFromCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: I think that `SelectFromCollection` and its class have another purpose. In context of that class I also looked at the [native Crypto API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (especially Wintrust.dll and cryptui.dll), but I found nothing useful to solve this problem.